# MySQL boolean search - how to filter out all results that do not contain at least 2 input strings?

Tags: mysql, search, boolean

Does anybody know how to narrow down the MySQL boolean **Match/Against** search results to retrieve only those records which contain **at least 2** input words?

This is the query:

```
   SELECT it_title, en_title, genre, author, year, place, movie_id, url, place_it
        . FROM movies, locations, sets
        . WHERE MATCH (movies.it_title) AGAINST('$loc' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I would like to retrieve only matches who have at least 2 of the typed words, let's say:

- If user types: "midnight" I'd like to avoid "midnight in paris"
- If user types: "midnight in" then I'd like to show it.

Cheers,
Elisa

Answer (score 1):

That might be tricky in your example. MySQL's full-text search has a minimum word length (defaults to 4) so "in" wouldn't be indexed by default. "in" is also one of the default stop-words so again wouldn't be indexed by default. Also what about one-work film titles? Natural language searching is a notoriously difficult topic (google have dedicated years to getting their algorithms right). I'd recommend NOT creating your own algorithms.

Why not just use MySQL's natural language search (rather than the boolean). You could restrict the results to the top X results, or possibly to all results that score greater than X with an option for the user to search again/view all results etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your case just count words for $loc, for example if you're using php make an if statement with str_word_count($loc)>= 2

This is what I've found on [this site](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,358310,359347#msg-359347) about multiple word search for match against.

> After a little research I found out that if you want to search for multiple keywords you could just add space between each word. So if I want to perform a fulltext search on a table against words "apple, auto parts and apparel" then I would write it like this.

```
select * from tbl_name where match (col1, col2) AGAINST ('apple "auto parts" apparel' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```